# Regular expression with JavaScript URL redirect

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to redirect IE8 (and downwards) to a different page. I currently have the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var oldURL = document.location.href;
     var code = url.slice(-3);        
     window.location = "http://www.example.com/" + code;
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Of course this works if an IE8 visitor is on the address:

http://www.example.com/index.htm#!/ABC

but not if they're at:

http://www.example.com/index.htm#!/ABC/subpage  or http://www.example.com/index.htm#!/ABC/subpage/anotherpage

The code I want is always following a #!/ but I cannot control what trails it.

I went after some regular expression help here: http://txt2re.com/index-javascript.php3?s=http://www.example.com/index.htm%23!/ABC&18 but the solution seems a bit flakey if the URL structure changes in the future.

I expect the output ABC in each of the examples above.

What's the next step here? I would like to understand the most stable solution.

Comment: To be clear, explain precisely the outputs you expect for a representative set of inputs (i.e. "Given URLs *A*, *B*, *C* etcetera, I expect outputs *A'*, *B'*, *C'* etc.").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split on the hash value, which return an array of url string splitted by '/'

```
http://www.example.com/index.htm#!/ABC/subpage/anotherpage

var urlArray = window.location.hash.split('/');
["#!", "ABC", "subpage", "anotherpage"]
urlArray[1] -> "ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use:

```
window.location.hash
```